# Exception: Invalid argument:

Tags: javascript, urlfetch

```
"https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gZ_S/6aXESt.jpeg?fl=res,1920,1080,1|wrm,/watermark/sreality.png,10|shr,,20|jpg,90"
```

if the above URL I paste in the browser it loads the image, but if I use this URL within URLFetchApp it is giving me Exception: Invalid Argument.

Comment: Try url encode `fl` parameter

Comment: `new URL("https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gZ_S/6aXESt.jpeg?fl=res,1920,1080,1|wrm,/watermark/sreality.png,10|shr,,20|jpg,90")` doesn’t throw, so this can be parsed as a valid URL. `.searchParams.get("fl")` is `"res,1920,1080,1|wrm,/watermark/sreality.png,10|shr,,20|jpg,90"`.

Comment: before passing/appending it to the URL make sure you are encoding the URL param with the `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you for your prompt response., but I am using it in the google script. How can I exactly separate and pass in URLFetchApp.

Comment: @kunalpanchal Thank you for your response. Can you please explain, with code if possible?

Comment: @kunalpanchal This url is not generated by me . I have extracted from web. Now my idea is to download image directly from cnd center. If i paste same in browser it is working but in urlfetchapp it is not working. Now i don't know what is wrong with this URL

Comment: can you please share the code where you are fetching the URL in the app ?